# Write a function that takes 1 parameter: a string, s. It must return an integer denoting the length of the longest magical sub-sequence in s?

Tags: java, python

Consider a string s, consisting of one or more of the following letters: a, e, i, o, and u.

We define a magical subsequence of s to be a sequence of letters derived from s that contains all five vowels in order. This means a magical subsequence will have one or more a's followed by one or more e's followed by one or more i's followed by one or more o's followed by one or more u's. For example, if s = "aeeiooua", then "aeiou" and "aeeioou" are magical subsequences but "aeio" and "aeeioua" are not.

Write a function to find length of longest magical subsequence with parameter string s.

```
Input Format
String s composed of English vowels (i.e., a, e, i, o, and u).

Output Format
Count denoting the length of the longest magical subsequence in s.


    Sample Input 1
    aeiaaioooaauuaeiou



Sample Output 1
10

Explanation 1
In the table below, the component characters of the longest magical subsequence are red:
a   e   i   a   a   i   o   o   o   a   a   u   u   a   e   i   o   u

Sample Input 2
aeiaaioooaa

Sample Output 2
0

Explanation 2
String s does not contain the letter u, so it is not possible to construct a magical subsequence

I
```

So the java code of this problem goes like this .

```
import java.util.Arrays; import java.util.Scanner;
public class LongestMegicalSubsequence {
static int longestMegicalSubsequence(String s, char[] c) {

    // exit conditions
    if (s.length() == 0 || c.length == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (s.length() < c.length) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (s.length() == c.length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) != c[i]) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        return s.length();
    }

    if (s.charAt(0) < c[0]) {
        // ignore, go ahead with next item
        return longestMegicalSubsequence(s.substring(1), c);
    } else if (s.charAt(0) == c[0]) {

        return Math.max(Math.max(
                (1 + longestMegicalSubsequence(s.substring(1),
                        Arrays.copyOfRange(c, 1, c.length))),
                (1 + longestMegicalSubsequence(s.substring(1), c))),
                (longestMegicalSubsequence(s.substring(1), c)));
    } else {
        return longestMegicalSubsequence(s.substring(1), c);
    }
}

public static void main(String...s) {

    char[] chars = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
    System.out.print("PLEASE ENTER THE STRING");
    Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);

    String str = sc.next();

    System.out.println(longestMegicalSubsequence(str, chars));


}
}
```

I was just thinking to do this problem in python . 
But couldn't think of a pythonic  way to do it . I mean I convert each line of logic in python code but that is not my motive . Can you people suggest me a way to do it in python .

Comment: Yes: forget about the Java version, write the specs as test cases, then write your Python code against the tests. Seriously, what kind of answer do you expect ?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are even asking. You don't want to solve the problem in Java, but you also don't want to convert the code to Python? Huh?

Comment: @timgeb .I want to convert it to python only . 
But using some libraries , that could shorten the code length . Not just by following each line of java code and converting it back to python .

Comment: @Techno_Stud Could you please tell where you got this question from? I need to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a python version.

```
def f(input):
    pattern='aeiou'
    total=0
    c=0
    for x in input:
        if x==pattern[c]:
            c+=1
            if c==5:
                total += 5
                c=0
    return total
```

Text :

```
In [12]: f('aeiaaioooaauuaeiou')
10
```

Or, more arithmetic:

```
def f(input):
    pattern='aeiou'
    c=0
    for x in input:
        c += (x==pattern[c%5])
    print(c//5*5)
```

Comment: Thank you so much mate .

Comment: Wow . How do you do that @_@